# How get GameObject (in scene) in script which run command line (Unity3d)

Tags: unity-game-engine, command-line-interface

I use command line for run script in Unity3d:
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Unity.exe" -quit -batchmode -projectPath "path_to_project" -executeMethod Command.Do

In method "Do": I try get GameObject in scene:  GameObject.Find("Automation"), but result null(.

```
class Command
{
   static public void Do()
   {
    Debug.Log("Test");
    EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget(BuildTarget.Android);

    var scene = EditorBuildSettings.scenes[0];
    string name = scene.path.Substring(scene.path.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    name = name.Substring(0, name.Length - 6);

    SceneManager.LoadScene(0);

    var automationGo = GameObject.Find("Automation");
    System.Console.WriteLine("automationGo " + automationGo);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved:
instead  SceneManager.LoadScene(0) need use : EditorSceneManager.OpenScene(scene.path);

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this thread from Google and wants to run the game to test things headlessly (like me), here's all the info you'll need:

```cs
public class PlayTestsLoader : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static bool PlayTestsRunning = false;
    public static bool PlayTestsWantToStop = false;
    // Run with (note paths are Linux syntax - replace as needed)
    // ./Unity -projectPath ~/unityprojectname -executeMethod PlayTestsLoader.LoadTestScenes -logfile "~unityprojectname/logs.txt" -batchmode
    public static void LoadTestScenes()
    {
        try
        {
            EditorUserBuildSettings.SwitchActiveBuildTarget(BuildTargetGroup.Android, BuildTarget.Android); // Test Android code paths as if you were doing it manually in Editor
            EditorSceneManager.OpenScene($"Assets/Scenes/mainscene.unity"); // Load the scene in Editor - Not at play time!
            EditorApplication.isPlaying = true; // When this static method returns, setting isPlaying to true will start the game
            TestLog($"Entered playmode");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            TestLog($"Had exception {e}");
        }
        TestLog($"Complete PlayTestsLoader.LoadTestScenes");
    }

    static void TestLog(string log)
    {
        Debug.Log($"=== PlayTests === {log}");
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (PlayTestsRunning && PlayTestsWantToStop)
        {
            TestLog("ALL TESTS COMPLETED -- RETURNING 0");
            EditorApplication.Exit(0); // This will stop the game from running when you're done, and make the headless (invisible) editor exit
        }
    }

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        PlayTestsRunning = true;
        TestLog("PlayTestsLoader Monobehaviour started");
        StartCoroutine(PlayTestJourneyController());
    }
  
    IEnumerator PlayTestJourneyController()
    {
        yield return StartPvP();
        yield return SayHelloAfterPvP();
      
        PlayTestsWantToStop = true;
        yield return null;
    }
  
    IEnumerator StartPvP()
    {
        TestLog($"Hello from StartPvP");
        yield break;
    }
  
    IEnumerator SayHelloAfterPvP()
    {
        TestLog($"Hello from SayHelloAfterPvP");
        yield break;
    }
}
```

Basically this gets you setup with everything you need - Your update loop, your exit conditions, any coroutines, etc etc.